# Словил себя на мысли

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли говорить "словил себя на мысли"?

Comment: Славил, славлю и буду славить?

Comment: А не "словил на мысли"? Не опечатка ли?

Answer (score 2):

1. Может быть,  это  "***словить себя на мысли***". Тогда мы имеем просторечную форму выражения "***поймать себя на мысли***". В разговорной речи такой вариант допускается.

Толковый словарь Ушакова: ***СЛОВИТЬ***, соверш., кого-что (прост.). Поймать, схватить. Вора словили. Словить мяч.

2. **Славить себя на мысли**?

Нет, это неверно.

***Славить себя*** разрешается, например: *Сам Дух Божий **славил себя** в этой песни и возвестил устами Девы высокую тайну смирения и что смиренья требует от нас Бог*. [Н. В. Гоголь. Размышления о Божественной Литургии (1847)]

Но славить можно, например, ***стихами*** или ***в стихах***, то есть нужен Т.п. или П.п. с предлогом В.

Тогда получается: славить себя ***мыслями/в мыслях***.  Семантика не совсем обычная (это на усмотрение автора), но формальная грамматика верная.